# downloading a table from the web

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract a table from this [website](https://dataunodc.un.org/GSH_app) after clicking on "National Data". I know there is an option to download it directly but I'm very interested in web scraping and I want to learn. Previously, I used the Selenium package in Python for automating the process of selecting all the checkboxes containing the years and now I want to extract the table as a dataframe until the last page, in order to have the whole entries in my dataframe. I think the table id I want to **scrape** is 'DataTables_Table_26'.

I tried to do this for extracting the first table but it doesn't work.

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

table = soup.find_all('table', {'id':'DataTables_Table_26'})
```

If you need to see the previous lines of my code, just tell me. Thanks in advance.

This is the part of the html code where there is a table object:

[image]

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow, since it's a generic "How do I do the whole thing" rather than a specific issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to `read_html`() and store into `dataframe` and then `append` to each page traverse.

You need to install pandas using pip

> pip install pandas

Use infinite loop and traverse the page until next button available else break infinite loop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://dataunodc.un.org/GSH_app")
driver.maximize_window()

#Switch the iframe in order to access the link
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://unodc.shinyapps.io/GSH_App/']")))
#Click on National Data link
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//ul[@class="nav navbar-nav"]//a[text()="National Data"]'))).click()

#Get all checkbox which are not selected.
allchekbox=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='YearVar' and not(@checked='checked')]")))

for item in allchekbox:
    item.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.display.dataTable.no-footer")))
time.sleep(2)
html = driver.page_source
df=pd.read_html(str(html))[0]
while True:

    try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='paginate_button next']"))).click()
      time.sleep(1) #slowdown for loop to load data.
      html = driver.page_source
      df1 = pd.read_html(str(html))[0]
      #append data into dataframe
      df=df.append(df1,ignore_index=True)

    except:
      break

#load the data into csv file to verify all data
df.to_csv("testdata.csv")
print(df)
```

**Snapshot of CSV file after loaded.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good table scraper if you can get the link of the data, you just have to pass in which table to **scrape**:

```
#Main function
def getContent(link, filename, whichtable=0):
    result1 = requests.get(link)
    src1 = result1.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src1,'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('table')[whichtable]
    with open(filename,'w',newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for tr in table('tr'):
            row = [t.get_text(strip=True)for t in tr(['td','th'])]
            writer.writerow(row)


getContent('https://teams.technion.ac.il/residency-placements/', 'what.csv', whichtable=0)
df2= pd.read_csv('what.csv')
or
getContent('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films', 'what.csv', whichtable=0)


You can see it's a very good table __scraper__, and you should be able to use it on your site if you can get to the page with the actual table
```

This table **scraper** will read any table on a website, as long as you set whichtable, as some sites have more than one table